# How do I write an unknown number of lines into a textFile that has been created by my script?

Tags: python

I programmed a Simulator for the board game Risk that simulates the battles between defending and attacking troops.
I then added lines of code to create a text file named after a standard 'Battlerreport', followed by the date/time

I wrote the simulating code with while loops and if statements so the code outputs the modified number of attacking troops after every 'roll'

**My question is: How do I get python to create the file and THEN run the simulation AND write str(Number of attackers) + str(Number of defenders) after each 'roll' into the text file, so the entire battle development is displayed?**

Basically I need to define a starting point where the file first gets edited and then loop the writing so Python writes the two numbers in one line, then switches to the next line and so on... The main problem is, that python doesn't know how many rolls there will be before the code gets executed, so in that way the lines the script is supposed to edit is unknown..? PLS HELP :/ For anyone that wants to check my code and/or has suggestions for improvement:

```py
from time import strftime
from os import path

def createFile(dest):   
    '''
    The script creates a text file at the passed in location, 
    names file based on date
    '''

    #FileName= Battlereport_Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute_Second.txt
    name = 'Battlereport_' + strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.txt")
    if not (path.isfile(dest + name)):
        saveFile = open(dest + name, 'w')

        o = ["1", "21", "31"]
        t = ["2", "22"]
        e = ["3", "23"]

        date_day = strftime("%d")
        for date_day in o:
            date = strftime("%B %dst, %Y at %H:%M:%S")
        for date_day in t:
            date = strftime("%B %dnd, %Y at %H:%M:%S")
        for date_day in e:
            date = strftime("%B %drd, %Y at %H:%M:%S")
        else:
            date = strftime("%B %dth, %Y at %H:%M:%S")

            if A > D:
                s = (str(A), str(D))
                text = 'Battle report from {}\n\n\n\n{}\n\nCongratulations! The attacking force has conquered the lands!'.format(date, s) 

            else:
                s = (str(A), str(D))
                text = 'Battle report from {}\n\n\n\n{}\n\nCongratulations! The defense has held strong!'.format(date, s)

            saveFile.write(str(text))

import random

A = int(input("Number of attacking troops: "))
D = int(input("Number of defending troops: "))

while A >= 5 and D >= 3:

    V = random.randint(1, 6)
    W = random.randint(1, 6)
    X = random.randint(1, 6)

    Y = random.randint(1, 6)
    Z = random.randint(1, 6)

    Attacker = [V, W, X]
    Attacker2 = [V, W]
    Defender = [Y, Z]

    a1 = max([Attacker])
    a2 = max(n for n in Attacker if n != a1)
    d1 = max([Defender])
    d2 = max(n for n in Defender if n != d1)

    a1_2 = max([Attacker2])
    a2_2 = max(n for n in Attacker2 if n != a1_2)

    if a1 > d1:
        D -= 1
    else:
        A -= 1
    if a2 > d2:
        D -= 1
    else:
        A -= 1
    print(str(A), str(D))

    if A >= 4 and D > 2:

        if a1 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2 > d2:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))


    if A >= 4 and D == 2:

        if a1 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2 > d2:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))  

    if A == 3 and D == 2:
        if a1_2 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2_2 > d2:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            if A == 1:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")

    if A == 3 and D >= 2:

        if a1_2 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2_2 > d2:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            if A == 1:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")


    if A == 2 and D >= 2:

        if [V] > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            if A == 1:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")


while A >=2 and D == 1:

    V = random.randint(1, 6)
    W = random.randint(1, 6)
    X = random.randint(1, 6)

    Y = random.randint(1, 6)
    Z = random.randint(1, 6)

    Attacker = [V, W, X]
    Attacker2 = [V, W]
    Defender = [Y, Z]


    a1 = max([Attacker])
    a2 = max(n for n in Attacker if n != a1)
    d1 = max([Defender])
    d2 = max(n for n in Defender if n != d1)

    a1_2 = max([Attacker2])
    a2_2 = max(n for n in Attacker2 if n != a1_2)
    s = (str(A), str(D))  


    if A >= 4 and D == 1:

        if a1 > [Y]:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1   
            print(str(A), str(D))    




    if A == 3 and D == 1:

        if a1_2 > [Y]:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))



    if A == 2 and D == 1:
        if V > Y:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))
            print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    destination = 'C:\\Users\\vannoyi\\Desktop\\Battlereport\\'
    createFile(destination)
    input('done')

saveFile.close()
```

This is what the textfile currently receives:

Battle report from March 04th, 2019 at 10:08:04

('19', '0')

Congratulations! The attacking force has conquered the lands!

I don't only want the Troop count at the end of the battle, I want to see the development in the file from 42 attacking and 23 defending troops all the way down to the troops that are left over at the end of the battle!

**I greatly appreciate any kind of help!**

Comment: Please considering re-phrasing your question to make it more accessible. Hopefully this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can provide some pointers

Comment: Please, please format that code with proper indentations. It's Python after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code so that the amount of attackers and defenders gets stored in a list after each roll. Then when you call the createFile() function I write this list to the file.

I added comments above every line I changed to make it more clear.

```
from time import strftime
from os import path

def createFile():   
    '''
    The script creates a text file at the passed in location, 
    names file based on date
    '''

    #FileName= Battlereport_Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute_Second.txt
    name = 'Battlereport_' + strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.txt")
    if not (path.isfile(name)):
        saveFile = open(name, 'w')

        o = ["1", "21", "31"]
        t = ["2", "22"]
        e = ["3", "23"]

        date_day = strftime("%d")
        for date_day in o:
            date = strftime("%B %dst, %Y at %H:%M:%S")
        for date_day in t:
            date = strftime("%B %dnd, %Y at %H:%M:%S")
        for date_day in e:
            date = strftime("%B %drd, %Y at %H:%M:%S")
        else:
            date = strftime("%B %dth, %Y at %H:%M:%S")

            #write the troops list to the file
            for i in troops:
                saveFile.write(str(i) + "\n")

            if A > D:
                s = (str(A), str(D))
                text = 'Battle report from {}\n\n\n\n{}\n\nCongratulations! The attacking force has conquered the lands!'.format(date, s) 

            else:
                s = (str(A), str(D))
                text = 'Battle report from {}\n\n\n\n{}\n\nCongratulations! The defense has held strong!'.format(date, s)

            saveFile.write(str(text))

import random

A = int(input("Number of attacking troops: "))
D = int(input("Number of defending troops: "))

#create a list that contains the number of troops
troops = [(A, D)]

while A >= 5 and D >= 3:

    s = (str(A), str(D))

    V = random.randint(1, 6)
    W = random.randint(1, 6)
    X = random.randint(1, 6)

    Y = random.randint(1, 6)
    Z = random.randint(1, 6)

    Attacker = [V, W, X]
    Attacker2 = [V, W]
    Defender = [Y, Z]

    a1 = max([Attacker])
    a2 = max(n for n in Attacker if n != a1)
    d1 = max([Defender])
    d2 = max(n for n in Defender if n != d1)

    a1_2 = max([Attacker2])
    a2_2 = max(n for n in Attacker2 if n != a1_2)

    if a1 > d1:
        D -= 1
    else:
        A -= 1
    if a2 > d2:
        D -= 1
    else:
        A -= 1
    print(str(A), str(D))
    #add the changed troops number to the list
    troops.append((A, D))

    if A >= 4 and D > 2:

        if a1 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2 > d2:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))
        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))


    if A >= 4 and D == 2:

        if a1 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2 > d2:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))
        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))

    if A == 3 and D == 2:
        if a1_2 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2_2 > d2:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            if A == 1:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")

        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))

    if A == 3 and D >= 2:

        if a1_2 > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
        if a2_2 > d2:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            if A == 1:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")

        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))


    if A == 2 and D >= 2:

        if [V] > d1:
            D -= 1
        else:
            A -= 1
            if A == 1:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")

        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))


while A >=2 and D == 1:

    V = random.randint(1, 6)
    W = random.randint(1, 6)
    X = random.randint(1, 6)

    Y = random.randint(1, 6)
    Z = random.randint(1, 6)

    Attacker = [V, W, X]
    Attacker2 = [V, W]
    Defender = [Y, Z]


    a1 = max([Attacker])
    a2 = max(n for n in Attacker if n != a1)
    d1 = max([Defender])
    d2 = max(n for n in Defender if n != d1)

    a1_2 = max([Attacker2])
    a2_2 = max(n for n in Attacker2 if n != a1_2)
    s = (str(A), str(D))  


    if A >= 4 and D == 1:

        if a1 > [Y]:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1   
            print(str(A), str(D))
        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))




    if A == 3 and D == 1:

        if a1_2 > [Y]:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))



    if A == 2 and D == 1:
        if V > Y:
            D -= 1
            if D == 0:
                print(str(A), str(D))
                print("Congratulations! The attacking force has won!")

        else:
            A -= 1
            print(str(A), str(D))
            print("Congratulations! The defense held strong!")

        #add the changed troops number to the list
        troops.append((A, D))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    destination = 'C:\\Users\\vannoyi\\Desktop\\Battlereport\\'
    createFile(destination)
    input('done')

saveFile.close()
```